# How do I Embed a Kestrel WebServer in a C# .NET 4.0 App

Tags: c#, .net, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I have a backend system developed with C# .NET 4.0. I wish to embed the light weight web server Kestrel on it. Has anyone done so? or can point me to a direction how to do such?

Cheers!

Comment: How doesn't self-hosted WCF suit your needs?

Comment: Wcf is only communications. I want to host my webpages on the server.. so the user does not need to install any webservers

Comment: If you want to host web-pages on your server, then WCF is not applicable, either hosted on Kestrel or self-hosted, because WCF is for services, you are right here. Perhaps, you want to go for WebAPI. **"so the user does not need to install any webservers"** - this part is absolutely unclear. Which users? Users never need to install any web-servers, they consume it, either it is WCF or ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 2):

[**KestrelHttpServer** : "A cross platform web server for ASP.NET ***Core***."](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer). (emphasis added by me).

So that's no, and no.

Comment: I would personally say that it is not mutually exclusive. Kestrel is a web server for ASP.NET Core, but you technically can host services declared to be used for WCF and compatible with WCF (http\https bindings only) in ASP.NET Core using custom middleware. However, as per semantics it is not very clear for me if they actually still would be WCF services in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it, but of course only by opening Kestrel which serves a .net core application as a background process. The .Net Framework app communicates with the .net core app via inter-process communication over a websocket on localhost.